# Which version of Debian does Kali Linux Rolling use? Jessie or Wheezy

Tags: debian, kali-linux, version

Which version of Debian does Kali Linux Rolling use?

```
root@TRax:~# uname -a
Linux TRax 4.9.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.13-1kali3 (2017-03-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@TRax:~# lsb_release --codename
Codename:   kali-rolling
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Rather than Kali basing itself off standard Debian releases (such as Debian 7, 8, 9) and going through the cyclic phases of “new, mainstream, outdated”, the Kali rolling release feeds continuously from **Debian testing**, ensuring a constant flow of the latest package versions.

https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-rolling-edition-2016-1/

Comment: I need to install Cloudera (CDH-5) on Kali rolling.CDH has packages for debian versions wheezy, trusty and precise. Which one should I download? I tried wheezy but its not compatible.

Comment: "The single most common causes of a broken Kali Linux installation are following unofficial advice, and particularly arbitrarily populating the system’s sources.list file with unofficial repositories. The following post aims to clarify what repositories should exist in sources.list, and when they should be used.

Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL." ---saying that there is a Jessie version - https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html. Trusty & Precise are Ubuntu.